# C++ - Casting a variable of {superclass} to {subclass}

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

As a practice program after learning C++, I am developing a text-based game. I am using object-oriented programming style for handling the worlds/their objects. Here's the necessary information about their definitions:

```
class Object
{
    private:
        unsigned int id;
    public:
        unsigned int getID() const { return id; }
};
class TakeableObject: public Object
{
   ...
};
class EdibleObject: public TakeableObject
{
    private:
        float healthEffect;
        float staminaEffect;
    public:
        float getHealthEffect() const { return healthEffect; }
        float getStaminaEffect() const { return staminaEffect; }
};
class Player
{
    private:
        float health;
        float stamina;
        TakeableObject inventory[256];
    public:
        eat(const EdibleObject* o)
        {
            health += o->getHealthEffect();
            stamina += o->getStaminaEffect();
        }
        eat(int id)
        {
            if (inventory[id] == NULL)
                throw "No item with that ID!";
            eat((EdibleObject) inventory[id]);
            inventory[id] = NULL;
        }
};
```

So my question is - in `Player::eat(int)`, is there a way I can make sure the `Object` at `Player::inventory[id]` is an `EdibleObject` (perhaps through exception handling?)

Comment: Stackoverflow should be updated to reject questions that do not contain a question mark. :-)

Comment: Sorry, mishit the Enter key. I'm finishing the post

Comment: Why was this question closed ? It's not **that** unclear.

Comment: Why do you use a fixed size array for `inventory`? Make it a `map` and your problem would solve itself.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Each object has a specific ID - in the world there can only be 255 objects due to protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User dynamic cast to check the object type at runtime.

Or you can use a virtual function with default definition in parent and can update it as per your requirement in derived classes.

Instead of `eat((EdibleObject) inventory[id]);` use the following

```
EdibleObject *temp = dynamic_cast<EdibleObject *>( &inventory[id] );
if(temp) { eat(*temp); }
else { /* Handling */ }
```

Your code suffers [Object splicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), make sure to get rid of that first.

Comment: An answer without a question! LOL!

Comment: StackOverflow Jeopardy!

Comment: Please reread the question - it wasn't finished.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the slicing problem, I didn't even know it existed (because  it doesn't exist in  Java)

Comment: You are right, because in Java everything is a reference. In C++, objects and references are different.